# Why collision rate scales with square of number density

Tags: collision

I have a system with $n$ objects in them, cross-sectional area of each is $\sigma$, their average speed is $v$. My notes are telling me that the rate of collision scales roughly as $$R\approx n^2\sigma v$$

I don't care about factors of order unity. Intuitively, how can I see that $n$ squared? (Ie why is it not just $n$?)

Answer (score 1):

Because you need two particles to actually collide, not just one? Each particle of the ensemble (one $n$) has a certain chance to collide with each of the rest (another $n$). This ignores multi-particle collision events though, but if your density is not very large, these collisions can be considered rare.

Actually, $n(n-1)$ might be more precise, but since usually $n$ is very large, this is the same as $n^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a very large grid where a fraction of $n$ of the grid cells is occupied with particle and the remaining fraction $(1-n)$ is empty. Each grid cell can only have one particle.

The probability of a grid cell containing a particle is $n$.

The probability of two neighbouring grid cells both having a particle is $n\cdot n=n^2$. Likewise the probability of two particles having an encounter in a real system scales with $n^2$ even though the prefactor will be different.

For completion sake if you call $X$ the number of particles in two neighbouring grid cells then we have
\begin{align}
P(X=0)&=(1-n)^2\\
P(X=1)&=2n(1-n)\\
P(X=2)&=n^2
\end{align}